# retirement saving calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

Well I built out this calculator and I'm having trouble how to loop through number of years investing money into an savings account and have that add with the interest and present value until the number of annual payments end.

My problem is that the annual payment of $1,000 is added all 35 years which is throwing off my total interest. Also it's adding to the present value when I calculate previous balance + total interest and total invested. How can I create a loop that would stop when it reaches 15 years?

I'm also using [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ADkx_bkxK2HQnXmSnYtuuvDzQOA36_Q6_drwJf5MQvc/edit?usp=sharing) for the formulas.

here my code so far:

```
var current_age = 30;
var age_retirement = 65;
var expected_annual_return = 0.06;
var annual_payment = $1000;
var annual_payments = 15;
      var interest = 0;
      var total_interest = 0;
      var total_amount_invested = 0;
      var cumulative_payments;
      var amount_invested;

  if (total_years_until_retirement <= annual_payments) {
  var total_amount_invested = (total_years_until_retirement * annual_payment + present_value);
  var total_improved_amount = total_amount_invested * annual_payment;
  console.log("This is the if statement");
  } else {
    cumulative_payments = present_value + annual_payment;
    amount_invested = cumulative_payments + annual_payment;

    console.log("This is the else statement");
    console.log("The total amount invested is: "+total_amount_invested);
    };

  for (i = 0; i <= (actual_total_years_until_retirement); i++) {
    interest = present_value * expected_annual_return;
    present_value = present_value + annual_payment + interest;
    total_interest += interest;
  };
```

Comment: suggest you grab a pencil and paper and write the formulas down you need first, then work that into your code

Comment: i did that but I not sure how to stop the annual payments from adding into the from time until retirement. if that made any senses

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the loop after it reaches the 15 year count place the following in your for loop

Javascript:

```
       //if i equals 15
       if(i === 15){//begin if then

        //exit the loop
        return false;


      }//end if then
```

So if you want to stop adding the payment after fifteen years you could do something like this:

Example:

```
 for (i = 0; i <= (actual_total_years_until_retirement); i++) {//begin if then

//if the loop is not on its fifteenth iteration
if(i !== 15){//begin if then else

interest = present_value * expected_annual_return;
present_value = present_value + annual_payment + interest;

total_interest += interest;

}
else{

 //perform same calculations as above the remove the annual payment
 interest = present_value * expected_annual_return;
 present_value = present_value + interest;

total_interest += interest;


}//end if then else

    }//end for loop
```